# Eliminating missing pixels in NDVI time series analysis by temporal gap filling with linear interpolation to get a smooth result

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, filter, time-series

The code is running correctly but it doesn't give me a smoothened result. Anyone who can help me out?

```
var startDate = '2015-01-01';
var endDate = '2023-12-31';

var images = sentinel.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate,endDate)).filterBounds(geometry)
print(images);

var ndvi = function(image){
  var ndv = image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
  return ndv.copyProperties(image,['system:index', 'system:time_start'])
}
var ndvi = images.map(ndvi);
var filtered = sentinel
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry))
// Write a function for Cloud masking
function maskCloudAndShadowsSR(image) {
  var cloudProb = image.select('MSK_CLDPRB');
  var cloud = cloudProb.lt(5);
  var scl = image.select('SCL'); 
  var shadow = scl.eq(3); // 3 = cloud shadow
  var cirrus = scl.eq(10); // 10 = cirrus
  // Cloud probability less than 5% or cloud shadow classification
  var mask = (cloud.and(cirrus.neq(1)).and(shadow.neq(1)));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}
var filtered = filtered.map(maskCloudAndShadowsSR)

var filtered = filtered.map(function(image) {
  var timeImage = image.metadata('system:time_start').rename('timestamp')
  var timeImageMasked = timeImage.updateMask(image.mask().select(0))
  return image.addBands(timeImageMasked)
})

var days = 30
var millis = ee.Number(days).multiply(1000*60*60*24)

var maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
  difference: millis,
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

var lessEqFilter = ee.Filter.lessThanOrEquals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})
var greaterEqFilter = ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

var filter1 = ee.Filter.and(maxDiffFilter, lessEqFilter)
 
var join1 = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'after',
  ordering: 'system:time_start',
  ascending: false})
   
var join1Result = join1.apply({
  primary: filtered,
  secondary: filtered,
  condition: filter1
})

var filter2 = ee.Filter.and(maxDiffFilter, greaterEqFilter)
 
var join2 = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'before',
  ordering: 'system:time_start',
  ascending: true})
   
var join2Result = join2.apply({
  primary: join1Result,
  secondary: join1Result,
  condition: filter2
})

var interpolateImages = function(image) {
  var images = ee.Image(image)
  // We get the list of before and after images from the image property
  // Mosaic the images so we a before and after image with the closest unmasked pixel
  var beforeImages = ee.List(image.get('before'))
  var beforeMosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(beforeImages).mosaic()
  var afterImages = ee.List(image.get('after'))
  var afterMosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(afterImages).mosaic()
  // Get image with before and after times
  var t1 = beforeMosaic.select('timestamp').rename('t1')
  var t2 = afterMosaic.select('timestamp').rename('t2')
  var t = images.metadata('system:time_start').rename('t')
  var timeImage = ee.Image.cat([t1, t2, t])
  var timeRatio = timeImage.expression('(t - t1) / (t2 - t1)', {
    't': timeImage.select('t'),
    't1': timeImage.select('t1'),
    't2': timeImage.select('t2'),})

  // Compute an image with the interpolated image y
  var interpolated = beforeMosaic
    .add((afterMosaic.subtract(beforeMosaic).multiply(timeRatio)))
  // Replace the masked pixels in the current image with the average value
  var result = images.unmask(interpolated)
  return result.copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
}

var interpolatedCol = ee.ImageCollection(
  join2Result.map(interpolateImages))


print(ndvi);

var nd = ndvi.first().clip(geometry);
Map.addLayer(nd,{min:0,max:1,palette:['white','Green']},'NDVI');


var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
imageCollection: ndvi,
  regions:geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 250
});
print(chart);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the time series smoother, use the moving average function that is available in the below link:
https://www.open-geocomputing.org/OpenEarthEngineLibrary/#.ImageCollection.movingWindow

code example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/25c26ec2407966eea61a2621a104703b

Comment: Thanks a lot that is really helpful! Now I try to adapt this code for Sentinel as this data is better for my project. I have a problem with the reflectance bands and the memory capacity, would it be possible to solve this?

Comment: Welcome. I think it would be better to calculate your desired index such as NDVI and then apply the smoothing function on.

Comment: I solved the error in reflactance bands but I keep having a problem with memory limit. Any way to solve this?